# Is depth annotation in spring-data-neo4j not working?

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I hope you are able to help me:

## Goal

My goal is to fetch an entity with its direct neighbour.

## Setup

Say I have `Person` Class:

```
@NodeEntity(label = "Person")
public class Person {

    ...

    @Relationship(type = "HAS_FRIEND")
    private Person friend;

    ...
}
```

This is my `PersonRepository`:

```
public interface PersonRepository extends Neo4jRepository<Person, Long> {

    Person findByName(String name);

}
```

Now lets say I have 4 people
Jim, Bob, Alice, Peter
And they are related like this: Jim `HAS_FRIEND` Bob `HAS_FRIEND` Alice `HAS_FRIEND` Peter

## What I expect

A Depth of 1:

When calling findByName("Jim") it should return an instance of Person with

- name => "Jim"
- friend => an instance of Person with name "Bob"
- bob.friend => null

## Actual

I get a Person instance with all grandchildren
Jim
Jim.friend => Bob
Bob.friend => Alice

Jim.getFriend().getFriend().getFriend() => Peter

## What I tried so far

1. Usage of `@Depth(value = 2)` is not working, will return like **Actual**
2. Tried with `Query` and `Param` annotation:

```
    @Query("MATCH " +
         "(p:Person {name:{name}})" +
         "Return p")
```

3. `@JsonIgnoreProperties` is no option, because I need this chain in other cases

## Edit

I am using `spring-boot-starter-data-neo4j version 2.2.5`
which again is using `spring-data-neo4j version 5.2.5`

Comment: I tried to reproduce this within the testing setup of Spring Data Neo4j at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-neo4j/blob/8941dfbf8c596f4141943da865b86ee917c3665f/spring-data-neo4j/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/neo4j/queries/DerivedQueryTests.java#L494
as a starter. I set the `User` relationship to outgoing and modified the query that creates the test base to match your scenario. For me the `@Depth` is working with your expected behaviour.

Comment: Funny thing, tried to reproduce it again today... was working fine. Depth of 1 as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could not reproduce the behavior with my own test setup. Maybe working on old data within neo4j? I don't know.

If someone knows anything more, feel free to answer